# SKTMainView.h file not found

Tags: swift, skmaps

I've implemented both SKMaps and SDKTools exactly the way it is described in your docs, step by step in Swift *without* CocoaPods. However I cannot get the tools to work.
I have compared my project to the Swift Demo Project and I cannot find any differences.

The tools' docs don't say anything about a bridging header file that is needed, but since the demo project uses one, I copied it.
After that, when I try to build my project I get the following error message:

```
SDKTools/Navigation/SKTNavigationManager.h:16:9: 'SKTMainView.h' file not found
```

Has anyone encountered the same problem or has any idea on how to fix this?
Sidenode: Xcode asked me to replace all < with double quotes for the import to work in my bridging file.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check if you've set the Header Search Paths correctly (otherwise it won't know where to search the header files): https://www.dropbox.com/s/y3iun1d5gr32zwv/Header%20Search%20Paths.png?dl=0

Comment: Thanks, but I did that a couple of times. They are correct and still I get this error :(

Answer (score 0):

I implemented using Cocoapods and had the same issue. The only way I could get it to work was to remove the first parts and only put the following in my bridging file

```
#import "SKTNavigationManager.h"
```

Comment: Interesting. I tried the same thing, but it didn't solve it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in Build Settings the following options are correct:

- Objective-C Bridging Header
- Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name
- Header Search Paths (you must add "${PROJECT_DIR}/SDKTools" if the SDKTools folder is in the project folder, or "${PROJECT_DIR}/../SDKTools" if it is at the same level)

You can find [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rg2m05hmbyvrm89/SKTMainView_file_not_found.zip?dl=0) a demo project.

Answer (score 0):

I already faced up to this error! This may happen when header search path is not well configured. Especially, if you didn't switch the PROJECT_DIR line in "recursive" instead of "non-recursive"[image]

With this header search path configuration, SDKTools must be at same level than your .xcodeproj file 
[image]

Hope this could help !!